# Yarn: как включать скрипты и стили непосредственно в html-документы?

Tags: html, npm, скрипт, yarn, package.json

Начал изучать Yarn, но не понимаю как подключать скрипты (.js) и стили (.css) **непосредственно в html-файлы**.

Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, но назначение Yarn то же что и Composer, но только для front-end, верно?

Иными словами, если я использую Yarn для установки пакетов в каталог assets/vendor/, то мне нужен какой-то один скрипт по аналогии с `autoload.php`, который содержит ссылки на все зависимости по скриптам и стилям. Имеет ли к этому какое-то отношение скрипт `index.js`, который я указывал при создании проекта?

Я не хотел бы никак использовать node.js - платформа нужна мне лишь чтобы установить npm и затем Yarn. То есть фактически мне нужен лишь Composer но только для front-end. Хотелось бы при помощи такого пакетного менеджера подключать стили в разделе `<head></head>` и скрипты в конце html-документа.

Если я чего-то путаю или недопонимаю в архитектуре и назначении Yarn, поясните, пожалуйста, в комментариях. Спасибо.

UPDATE:

При помощи Yarn я устанавливаю два пакета, например:

```
>yarn add bootstrap
>yarn add datatables.net-bs5
```

Оба пакета установились в каталог `webroot/assets/vendor`

У меня есть две страницы index.html и orders.html, к которым нужно подключить скрипты и стили.

В **index.html** мне нужно подключить стили bootstrap, а в конце документы разместить скрипты. Вот таким образом:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
<head>

<body>
Home
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="bootstrap.js"/>
```

В **orders.html** нужно аналогично включить стили bootstrap и datatables, а в конце документы включить скрипты из обоих пакетов:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datatables.css">
<head>

<body>
Orders
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="bootstrap.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="datatables.js"/>
```

Можно ли это автоматизировать при помощи Yarn?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. Yarn это аналог npm

Comment: @AlexeyTen, но Yarn же используется как пакетный менеджер для зависимостей? Может ли он в принципе выполнять ту функциональность, о которой я упомянул?

Comment: Пакетный менеджер устанавливает пакеты, а не подключает их в загадочный header

Comment: Да, я исправил header на <head>, но что делать с установленными пакетами? Их же надо как-то подключать? Мой аналог с Composer верный? Или Yarn совсем для другого?

Comment: Быть может вам нужен webpack или gulp, но к yarn-у они имеют отношение только тем что тоже написаны на js